# Use precompiled drivers to build aosp

Tags: android, android-source

I want to build AOSP for my Samsung Galaxy S Advance. But STE doesn't share the driver's of our board. Now was my question is it possible to use the precompiled drivers (Which are in the Samsung opensource package I think? Kernel source is delivered by Samsung) to compile AOSP?

Comment: Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35103228/2327227  - it's not exactly mapping your question, but maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use pre-compiled drivers. Even building AOSP for some of the nexus devices requires downloading the binary blobs and adding them into your source tree so that the images are built and able to interact with some of the hardware like the sensors and camera in some cases. So what you are trying to do should be possible. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes but how? I mean I have the drivers but if I compile it just get a lot of error's

Comment: Can you post the errors? Normally if they are prebuilts you just need the binaries and there is a Android.mk that defines the module and it's essentially just copied into out/target/product/<product_name>/obj/. If you are getting build errors would need to see the errors to tell you what your specific problem is. If anything they might not be in the correct location in your source tree.