# Building Vanilla AOSP Rom with CM repos?

Tags: android, android-source, cyanogenmod, rom, repo

I'd like to know if I can build a pure Vanilla 6.0 ROM with CyanogenMod repos for my device.
Here they are:

[Device](https://github.com/CM-LG-MSM8226/android_device_lge_w7)

[Kernel](https://github.com/CM-LG-MSM8226/android_kernel_lge_msm8226)

Should I do some particular edits (excluded adding my device to "lunch")?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick try could be changing `$(call inherit-product, vendor/cm/config/common_full_phone.mk)` to `$(call inherit-product, build/target/product/full.mk)`.

This will use the AOSP default `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` (e.g. UI stuff like SystemUI, Launcher2 or platform relevant stuff like libpowermanager) which are mandatory for a working device (and some more, e.g. phone functionality). You can also use another, just look into `build/target/product` directory.

What can happen now is, that Cyanogen did some changes on these `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` which work no longer without some stuff on top defined in previously removed `vendor/cm/config/common_full_phone.mk`.

That is why I would personally go another way:

Just use your device specific product configuration (the device repo) and the vendor specific prebuilt libraries (generated by the `setup-makefiles.sh` script in your product configuration) and of course the kernel within the AOSP stack of your choice (e.g. vanilla 6.0).

If you are lucky it will work out of the box, but often there are some work arounds needed to make the prebuilt vendor libraries working. If so, your have to study the commit messages of the device repository to get some hints what the guys have done, who ported the device.

Regardless which way you are choosing, you probably need to add some configuration file, permission files and/or flags. For an orientation look into the Cyanogenmod [vendor_cm](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_vendor_cm) repository.

It could also be a good try to change to configuration in `vendor/cm/config/*.mk` to get a nearly vanilla Android.

I think for such a proposition you need time and patience. I hope I could give you some good starting points.

Comment: I just compiled it successfully, but the kernel crashes. I have some fastboot lines on the top left during the LG BootLogo screen.
Do you know if I have to make some edits to the kernel in order to boot it?

Comment: How to you know the kernel is crashing? Do you already have adbd running to use dmesg? Or are you able to trace the kernel externally Have you tried to use the prebuilt kernel from your device? Or have you tried to build the kernel on your own? If you have tried to build it on your own, make sure you use the correct defconfig, or to be sure use the prebuilt one. If you're already using the prebuilt one make check your init'rc's.

Comment: Well, a Dev of my device said that when I see the fastboot lines it means that dt.img didn't append to boot.img but I don't really know what he was talking about. Also, I used the one that the build process built. I tried taking an old one (Not from this ROM) but it also doesn't boot (Only LG Logo this time). I use a fork repo of the original one (github.com/GrinningFerret/android_kernel_lge_msm8226   - Forked from github.com/Quarx2k/android_kernel_lge_8226) What should I check in particular in my init.rc's?
Thank you so much.

Comment: So, you do not have a kernel log? A few possible problems are that the init.rc which should be run, cannot be found. It must be named in the following pattern: init.{ro.hardware}.rc. Another problem could be that {ro.hardware} is not set correctly. Also there could be a couple of problems within the init scripts. Anyway, to what's going wrong a kernel log is needed.

Comment: I have init.qcom.rc. Btw, I can't provide you a log, since ADB won't recognize the phone because it is stuck at LG Logo.

Comment: Yes, it stucks either in the kernel or in the init before spawning the adbd. I would expect the kernel to work. Concentrate on init. Check that the hardware specific stuff is kept from the original init configuration. And exchange the Android specific stuff with the configuration you can find in another init script specific to your Android version.

Comment: So, I have to check a file like this (https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_cyanogen_msm8939-common/blob/cm-13.0/rootdir/etc/init.qcom.rc) And see the changes between this and mine?

Comment: Yes, check this one for Android related differences to yours. And keep hardware specifics.

Comment: Well, I was able to pass the LG Logo but stuck on bootanimation..I took a logcat..Here it is: https://justpaste.it/rhkb

Comment: That's nice. This means the your graphics libraries are working. Looks like your boot loop ist regarded to the crashing media services in Android's ServiceManager. The other crashes seems not that problematic. I As there is no hint in the log why the media services are crashing, you can try to start debugging the media service.